# How to create key value pair inside XSLT and get value using key

Tags: xml, xslt

Inside XSLT I have state which is coming from XML and on corresponding to that state I have my own state code which I want to put in transformed XML.

Source XML:

```
<states>
<state>New York</state>
<state>California</state>
</states>
```

Expected Result:

```
<states>
    <state>NY</state>
    <state>CA</state>
</states>
```

As I have list of states so I can't use **when** or **If** statement so Is their  any optimized way to solve this problem in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you extend your question with an excerpt of the list of states(the mapping)?

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can put the mapping table in a global variable in the stylesheet. In pure 1.0 you can't do that, but the exslt:node-set() function, which many processors offer, makes it possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://example.com/my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="state" match="state" use="." />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="state">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('state', ., document(''))/@code"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<my:states>
    <state code="AL">Alabama</state>
    <state code="AK">Alaska</state>
    <state code="AZ">Arizona</state>
    <state code="AR">Arkansas</state>
    <state code="CA">California</state>
    <state code="CO">Colorado</state>
    <state code="CT">Connecticut</state>
    <state code="DE">Delaware</state>
    <state code="DC">District of Columbia</state>
    <state code="FL">Florida</state>
    <state code="GA">Georgia</state>
    <state code="HI">Hawaii</state>
    <state code="ID">Idaho</state>
    <state code="IL">Illinois</state>
    <state code="IN">Indiana</state>
    <state code="IA">Iowa</state>
    <state code="KS">Kansas</state>
    <state code="KY">Kentucky</state>
    <state code="LA">Louisiana</state>
    <state code="ME">Maine</state>
    <state code="MD">Maryland</state>
    <state code="MA">Massachusetts</state>
    <state code="MI">Michigan</state>
    <state code="MN">Minnesota</state>
    <state code="MS">Mississippi</state>
    <state code="MO">Missouri</state>
    <state code="MT">Montana</state>
    <state code="NE">Nebraska</state>
    <state code="NV">Nevada</state>
    <state code="NH">New Hampshire</state>
    <state code="NJ">New Jersey</state>
    <state code="NM">New Mexico</state>
    <state code="NY">New York</state>
    <state code="NC">North Carolina</state>
    <state code="ND">North Dakota</state>
    <state code="OH">Ohio</state>
    <state code="OK">Oklahoma</state>
    <state code="OR">Oregon</state>
    <state code="PA">Pennsylvania</state>
    <state code="RI">Rhode Island</state>
    <state code="SC">South Carolina</state>
    <state code="SD">South Dakota</state>
    <state code="TN">Tennessee</state>
    <state code="TX">Texas</state>
    <state code="UT">Utah</state>
    <state code="VT">Vermont</state>
    <state code="VA">Virginia</state>
    <state code="WA">Washington</state>
    <state code="WV">West Virginia</state>
    <state code="WI">Wisconsin</state>
    <state code="WY">Wyoming</state>
</my:states>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you prefer, you could place the list of states and their codes in an external XML document and lookup from there.

> As I have list of states so I can't use when or If statement

Actually, using `xsl:choose` could work just as well.

Comment: When I try to transform using your xslt It gives below error.                 Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/base/data/home/apps/s~xslttest-hrd2/5.391785634117992591/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.                  I am using http://xslttest.appspot.com/ for transformation one more thing can I call the above template to my other template?

Comment: You cannot use an online XSLT service to test this, because it requires an actual XSLT file to be found by the document() function.

Comment: @JyotishSingh Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the external file with the mappings and access the mappings. I used 'b1.xml' as the filename. It replaces the full-names with the short-name.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="StateMap" select="document('b1.xml')/StateMapping" />

  <xsl:template match="states">
    <states>        
      <xsl:apply-templates select="state" />
    </states>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="state">
    <xsl:variable name="toMap" select="text()" />
    <state><xsl:value-of select="$StateMap/Map[@name = $toMap]" /></state>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The external mapping file, which you should replace with your own, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StateMapping>
  <Map name="New York">NY</Map>
  <Map name="California">CA</Map>
</StateMapping>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<states>
  <state>NY</state>
  <state>CA</state>
</states>
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't use any external file.

Comment: Isn't your list of states in an external file like described in your question?

Comment: No, I mean my list should be inside XSLT.

Comment: Then you would have to create a `data island` inside the XSLT. Add a namespace `xmlns:data="http://...whatever"` at the top and include the external mapping file replacing the namespace of the top-level-element with `<data:StateMapping>` in this example. Then replace the expression in the variable with `document('')/data:StateMapping`.